# Can't boot into windows with Mojave

Tags: bootcamp, startup, bug, beta, mojave

So I just installed the Mojave public beta version 10.14, when I turn off my machine and use the option button and select Windows it is always booting into macOS.

Disk output
[image: disk output]

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE                IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         220.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                280.0 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +220.0 GB   disk1
                             Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            108.9 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 30.5 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

I should also mention I just tried to use bootchamp to reboot and got the following error

```
EFI found at IODeviceTree:/efi
Mount point for /Volumes/BOOTCAMP is /Volumes/BOOTCAMP
Mount point is '/Volumes/BOOTCAMP'
No BootX creation requested
No boot.efi creation requested
Firmware feature mask: 0xFF1FFF3F
Firmware features: 0xFD0FF53E
Legacy mode NOT suppported
Legacy mode not supported on this system
```

Comment: Betas are betas and are going to have beta problems. If you don't want beta problems then don't install the beta. If you (and you should) have a backup pre beta then you can restore from that backup.

Comment: This is one of the pitfalls of working with *beta* software - it's *gonna* have bugs.    First, hopefully, you have a backup.  Secondly, post the output of the command `diskutil list` so we can start somewhere in assisting you.

Comment: Please copy and paste terminal outputs instead of screenshots.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include the beta build details.  Saying 'public beta' doesn't indicate which beta.  Please see [this question and answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1714/88313) regarding asking questions about Apple's beta software.

Comment: Make sure you report the issue via the channels Apple provides for feedback about their beta stuff, so they can fix it in one of the various new upcoming beta versions before the real deal is released in the fall.

Comment: More comments than answers on this one....  Such is the life of beta-build testers!

Answer (score 1):

You might not get anyone willing to discuss NDA builds here, but I can assure you, if you have a backup you can simply follow the erase and install steps for 10.13 and wipe / start over once you’ve reported any bugs to Apple Support for whatever program provided you with the beta.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Of course - you need to consider a backup of the windows side and the Mac side. Also - someone might have better boot camp support ideas - even if they are drawn from shipping versions of the product.